# How was polarization interpreted when first discovered?

Tags: electromagnetism, polarization

Malus first discovered light polarization just before 1810, but Maxwells equation stuff came around 1860s, so how was polarization interpreted before the EM theory?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it deals with the history of  physics

Comment: @BobD is right in that this question is mostly physics history; it would be very appropriate for the https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ but I think this is still much "more" physics than say a question as to how to calculate the integral of a rational function even if that integral is useful in QFT. And I say much more, not just because the subject is dear to my heart, but also because one could learn quite a lot from understanding how such brilliant people as Malus, Young, Brewster, Fresnel, etc.,  could reconcile experimental results with their understanding of nature.

Comment: I  am especially fond of Fresnel's construction of Huygens principle which by now clearly has no other than historical importance nowadays as far as an explanation of the diffraction phenomenon; still I believe it would be a loss for anybody learning optics not to get acquainted with it. And if somebody were to ask a question on the construction and we would just send it to hsm, we would shortchange ourselves.

Comment: Inspired by the comment by @hyportnex, I did a quick search and found this: https://arago.elte.hu/sites/default/files/DSc-Thesis-2003-GaborHorvath-01.pdf. Those early folks were astounding!

Comment: Astonishingly, Malus concluded that his experiments *confirmed* the Newtonian molecular hypothesis, at the same time he correctly guessed the $\cos^2\theta$ law of intensity of the polarized wave upon rotation of the polarizer. The window in the article to which @EdV referred  was one of the Palais de Luxembourg... See Darrigol: A HISTORY OF OPTICS FROM GREEK ANTIQUITY TO THE NINETEENTH CENTURY pp191-193